# Composting: what is the ratio of volume of material in to compost out?

Tags: compost

Say you've got a compost heap, 1 full metre cube, with about 1 part green to 3 parts brown by volume. If this is left to break down, what volume of compost will be produced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my (extensive) experience, between a quarter and a third of the original volume, usually a quarter - and the ratio of green to brown should really be kept as close as possible to 50/50.

Comment: Oh I though the 50/50 was by weight, which is roughly 25/75 by volume due to the greens' water content.